# Missing artifact com.google.android:android:jar:4.4_r1

Tags: java, android, maven

I'm trying to use Android 4.4_r1 and Maven for a project but for some reason the version maxima maven let me use is 4.1.1.4

I know it is not possible redristribucion android.jar and therefore the necessary maven-android-sdk-deployer, I've cloned the project and have run the command

```
mvn clean install -Pall,with-javadoc
```

and install all libraries, later when i edit the `pom.xml` file i get the following error

```
Missing artifact com.google.android:android:jar:4.4_r1
```

I've checked into the path `~/.m2/repository/com/google/android/android` and i can see the following versions

```
1.5_r4  2.2.1  2.3.1  4.1.1.4  4.2.2_r2  4.3_r2  4.4  4.4_r1
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

From https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer -

> The android.jar artifacts in Maven central are available with the
>   groupId com.google.android, whereas this tool uses android.android to
>   avoid overlap.

This means that when using the Maven Android SDK deployer your pom.xml should reference the artifact like this -

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>android</groupId>
  <artifactId>android</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.2_r2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note: the 4.4_r1 is no longer shipped in the Android SDK as it has been replaced by 4.4.2_r2.

The 4.1.1.4 version was the last com.google.android:android version uploaded to Maven Central, that's why it's the latest one you can reference using com.google.android:android.